# Jquery DataTable with Ignited-Datatables CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

**Update:**

> I finally found the solution for this problem. If you face the same
>   problem as mine, you can try visit this [link](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/160896/P340/#1013662)

I am having problem when want to integrate [Jquery DataTables](http://datatables.net) with  [CodeIgniter Ignited-Datatables](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables) library

When I use the default DataTables **sServerMethod** property which is "GET", I got the json response with data from my php. However since CodeIgniter use post, I stuck at loading server data although the function return me correct json output.

[image]

So I follow this [guide](http://gvlatko.com/2012/datables-stuck-on-server-side-processing-solution-for-codeigniter-with-ignitedtables/)  to change the **sServerMethod** to "POST". Now I dont stuck at loading server data, but I dont get the data that I need.

JSON response using **sServerMethod** GET (get correct json, but stuck at loading server data as in the image)

```
{
"sEcho": 0,
"iTotalRecords": 10,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,
"aaData": [
    [
        "Munauwar",
        "Syed",
        "Mr",
        "6012345678",
        "0000-00-00",
        "basikal"
    ],        
    [
        "Mak",
        "Je Wei",
        "Mr",
        "6012345678",
        "0000-00-00",
        "motor"
    ]
],
"sColumns": "first_name,last_name,salutation,number,birthday,group_name"}
```

JSON response using **sServerMethod** POST

```
{
"sEcho": 1,
"iTotalRecords": 10,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 0,
"aaData": [],
"sColumns": "first_name,last_name,salutation,number,birthday,group_name"}
```

This is my javascript code

```
$('#table1').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,            
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "sAjaxSource": config.base_url + "contact/popup_contact",
        "sServerMethod": "POST"

    });
```

My function in contact controller

```
function popup_contact()
{
    $this->datatables
         ->select('first_name,last_name,salutation,number,birthday,group_name')
         ->from('tb_contact')
         ->join('tb_contact_group', 'tb_contact.contact_group_id = tb_contact_group.contact_group_id');          

    echo $this->datatables->generate();             

}
```

Comment: what does **"GET STUCK"** mean? Please you an inspector (google chrome/firebug/etc) and tell us what the error is...

Comment: I use firebug and unfortunately there is no error. I only get message loading data from server (see the image) when using "sServerMethod": "GET"

Comment: If you have the solution as an answer here Accept it. If not then there is another option for "Answer your own question" go ahead and explain the solution you found yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If the method above still doesn't work, then its because you have set: $config['csrf_protection'] = true; // in your config of Codeigniter

Simply add the aoData.push line first thing in your fnServerData call:

```
"fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({name: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>', value: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'});
                $.ajax({
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'url': sSource,
                    'data': aoData,
                    'success': fnCallback
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#smstable').dataTable({
"bProcessing": true,
"bServerSide": true,
"iDisplayLength": 20,
//"bPaginate": true,
"bAutoWidth": false,
"iDisplayStart": 0,
"bLengthChange": false,//for sorting 10,20,30,50 ....
"sAjaxSource": "././myadmin/ajaxadmin/dt_sms",
"aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"aoColumns":[
    {"bSearchable": false,"bSortable": false,"bVisible": false},
    {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
    {"bSearchable": false,"bSortable": false},
    {"bSearchable": true,"bSortable": true},
    {"bSearchable": false,"bSortable": true},
    {"bSearchable": false,"bSortable": false}
],
"fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
    $.ajax(
          {
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type'  : 'POST',
            'url'    : sSource,
            'data'  : aoData,
            'success' : fnCallback
          }
      );//end ajx
    // console.log(fnCallback);
}
```

});//end datable

```
Just check my code and check if you missed something. That code works very fine with me.
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you got stuck on loading data from server.....it's basically cause by column set. 
Just count the "aoColumns" array and make sure is exactly equal to the table head set in your view file.

It's has happened to me time and again.....and the only solution has always been the column array set.