# I want to convert this query in codeigniter to Ignited datatable query

Tags: codeigniter, datatable, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I dont know how to convert this long model function to ignited datatable query. I have done small select functions with ignited datatables.Anybody know???
I have no idea about how to covert it. Is there any functions to do it?

```
   public function fetch_data() {

              $this->db->from('jil_requirements');
              $this->db->join('jil_users', 'jil_requirements.rqm_userid=jil_users.usr_id', 'left');
              $this->db->join('jil_merchants', 'jil_requirements.rqm_createdempid=jil_merchants.mer_id', 'left');
              $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_permission!=', '4');
              $this->db->order_by("jil_requirements.rqm_id", "desc");
              $query =  $this->db->get();  
              if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
              foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                 $this->db->select('count(jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid) as total'); 
                $this->db->from('jil_mrorfq'); 
               $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid', 'left'); 
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
                  $query2= $this->db->get()->row_object();
                 $row->total_count = $query2->total;    
                  $this->db->select('count(jil_quotemjdetail.qud_requirementid) as quotemjtotal'); 
                $this->db->from('jil_quotemjdetail'); 
               $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_quotemjdetail.qud_requirementid', 'left'); 
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
                  $query3= $this->db->get()->row_object();
                  $row->quotemj_total = $query3->quotemjtotal;

                   $this->db->select('count(jil_quotejcdetail.qud_requirementid) as quotejctotal'); 
                $this->db->from('jil_quotejcdetail'); 
               $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id= jil_quotejcdetail.qud_requirementid', 'left'); 
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
                  $query4= $this->db->get()->row_object();
                  $row->quotejc_total = $query4->quotejctotal;

                    $this->db->select('count( jil_pocjdetail.pocd_requirementid) as pocjtotal'); 
                $this->db->from('jil_pocjdetail'); 
               $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=  jil_pocjdetail.pocd_requirementid', 'left'); 
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
                  $query5= $this->db->get()->row_object();
                  $row->pocj_total = $query5->pocjtotal;

                   $this->db->select('count(jil_pojmdetail.pojd_requirementid) as pojmtotal'); 
                $this->db->from('jil_pojmdetail'); 
               $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=  jil_pojmdetail.pojd_requirementid', 'left'); 
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
                  $query6= $this->db->get()->row_object();
                  $row->pojm_total = $query6->pojmtotal;


                 $data[] = $row;
                        }
                       return $data;
                    }
                    return false;
               }
```

Comment: Did n't understand the database query requirement . But i guess you are looking for something like this : https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables , http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-1/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355542/jquery-datatable-with-ignited-datatables-codeigniter  ..  Not relevant to this question, you can use the Join of tables instead of calling multiple queries inside the loop .

Comment: but i want to get the result from another tables's result

Comment: If so, you can use the queries . Do the links point to your requirement ?

Comment: @KiranKrishnan yes my requirement.can you help?

Comment: yes i done join,but i dnt knw hw this convert :(

Comment: @devpro r u there???

Comment: yes, is it working fine?? or getting error?

Comment: @devpro it is working, i want it to be converted to ignited datatable query.can you help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646188/i-want-to-convert-this-query-in-codeigniter-to-ignited-datatable-query

Answer (score 1):

```
 $this->db->select('count(jil_quotemjdetail.qud_requirementid) as quotemjtotal'); 
                $this->db->from('jil_quotemjdetail'); 
               $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_quotemjdetail.qud_requirementid', 'left'); 
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
                  $query3= $this->db->get()->row_object();
                  $row->quotemj_total = $query3->quotemjtotal;

                   $this->db->select('count(jil_quotejcdetail.qud_requirementid) as quotejctotal'); 
                $this->db->from('jil_quotejcdetail'); 
               $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id= jil_quotejcdetail.qud_requirementid', 'left'); 
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
                  $query4= $this->db->get()->row_object();
                  $row->quotejc_total = $query4->quotejctotal;

                    $this->db->select('count( jil_pocjdetail.pocd_requirementid) as pocjtotal'); 
                $this->db->from('jil_pocjdetail'); 
               $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=  jil_pocjdetail.pocd_requirementid', 'left'); 
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
                  $query5= $this->db->get()->row_object();
                  $row->pocj_total = $query5->pocjtotal;

                   $this->db->select('count(jil_pojmdetail.pojd_requirementid) as pojmtotal'); 
                $this->db->from('jil_pojmdetail'); 
               $this->db->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=  jil_pojmdetail.pojd_requirementid', 'left'); 
               $this->db->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
                  $query6= $this->db->get()->row_object();
                  $row->pojm_total = $query6->pojmtotal;


                 $data[] = $row;
                        }
                       return $data;
                    }
                    return false;
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to load the ignited dataTables library.

```
    $this->load->library('datatables');
```

OR

add it to Autoloader for automatic loading when your Codeigniter application starts.

After that, change all

```
      $this->db->
```

in your queries to

```
     $this->datatables
```

Finally you have to use this to encode the data in json array

```
      $this->datatables->generate();
```

Lemme know if i can still be of help

**UPDATE**

```
public function fetch_data() {

          $this->datatables->from('jil_requirements');
          $this->datatables->join('jil_users',         'jil_requirements.rqm_userid=jil_users.usr_id', 'left');
          $this->datatables->join('jil_merchants', 'jil_requirements.rqm_createdempid=jil_merchants.mer_id', 'left');
          $this->datatables->where('jil_requirements.rqm_permission!=', '4');
          $this->datatables->order_by("jil_requirements.rqm_id", "desc");
          $query =  $this->datatables->get();  

         if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

          foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
             $this->datatables->select('count(jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid) as total'); 
            $this->datatables->from('jil_mrorfq'); 
           $this->datatables->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid', 'left'); 
           $this->datatables->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
              $query2= $this->datatables->get()->row_object();
             $row->total_count = $query2->total;    
              $this->datatables->select('count(jil_quotemjdetail.qud_requirementid) as quotemjtotal'); 
            $this->datatables->from('jil_quotemjdetail'); 
           $this->datatables->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=jil_quotemjdetail.qud_requirementid', 'left'); 
           $this->datatables->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
              $query3= $this->datatables->get()->row_object();
              $row->quotemj_total = $query3->quotemjtotal;

               $this->datatables->select('count(jil_quotejcdetail.qud_requirementid) as quotejctotal'); 
            $this->datatables->from('jil_quotejcdetail'); 
           $this->datatables->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id= jil_quotejcdetail.qud_requirementid', 'left'); 
           $this->datatables->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
              $query4= $this->datatables->get()->row_object();
              $row->quotejc_total = $query4->quotejctotal;

                $this->datatables->select('count( jil_pocjdetail.pocd_requirementid) as pocjtotal'); 
            $this->datatables->from('jil_pocjdetail'); 
           $this->datatables->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=  jil_pocjdetail.pocd_requirementid', 'left'); 
           $this->datatables->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
              $query5= $this->datatables->get()->row_object();
              $row->pocj_total = $query5->pocjtotal;

               $this->datatables->select('count(jil_pojmdetail.pojd_requirementid) as pojmtotal'); 
            $this->datatables->from('jil_pojmdetail'); 
           $this->datatables->join('jil_requirements', 'jil_requirements.rqm_id=  jil_pojmdetail.pojd_requirementid', 'left'); 
           $this->datatables->where('jil_requirements.rqm_id',$row->rqm_id);
              $query6= $this->datatables->get()->row_object();
              $row->pojm_total = $query6->pojmtotal;

               echo $this->datatables->generate();

           }
```

Comment: are you sure? about this?

Comment: I don't understand what you re trying to achieve with this all these queries together.

Comment: Can you explain...so, I can be of help.....I understand each separate table query but why will you be putting all of'em together.

Comment: inner queries depends on that foreach result

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your controller and see if its working

```
public function fetch_data() 
{ 
 $this->load->library("datatables");
 $query =  $this->datatables
        ->select('jil_requirements.*,count(jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid) as total,count(jil_quotemjdetail.qud_requirementid) as quotemjtotal,count(jil_quotejcdetail.qud_requirementid) as quotejctotal,count( jil_pocjdetail.pocd_requirementid) as pocjtotal,count(jil_pojmdetail.pojd_requirementid) as pojmtotal')
        ->from('jil_requirements')
        ->join('jil_users', 'jil_requirements.rqm_userid=jil_users.usr_id', 'left')
        ->join('jil_merchants', 'jil_requirements.rqm_createdempid=jil_merchants.mer_id', 'left')
        ->join('jil_mrorfq', 'jil_mrorfq.rfq_requirementid = jil_requirements.rqm_id', 'left')
        ->join('jil_quotemjdetail', 'jil_quotemjdetail.qud_requirementid = jil_requirements.rqm_id', 'left')
        ->join('jil_pocjdetail', 'jil_pocjdetail.pocd_requirementid = jil_requirements.rqm_id', 'left')
        ->join('jil_pojmdetail', 'jil_pojmdetail.pojd_requirementid = jil_requirements.rqm_id', 'left')
        ->where('jil_requirements.rqm_permission!=', '4');  
    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

Comment: @Angel check now for testing purpose only with my updated code is it giving you your desired output  ?? I am working on your complex structure to give it a simple look first then we will convert this to Ignited datatables ... :)

Comment: i got some errors in console like undefined function order_by() etc

Comment: @Angel Okk then remove order by and try... Ignited datatables dont support `order_by` so use it in your jquery `"aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]],`

Comment: can you available after 2 hours?

Comment: i wil be back here on 7 pm? if you have time,plz come on that time

Comment: See you tomorrow then ;) Rest means something to me mam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105226/discussion-between-angel-and-praveen-kumar).